# CKeditor changing font format automatically

Tags: php, formatting, ckeditor

If I write something (example TEST1 and TEST2)in `ckeditor`, and retrive it, the font are displayed as following
The only format I applied is bold.

#### TEST1

## TEST2

By removing the format (clear format), it is cleared. But why does this happen?
Why Ckeditor adds formatting on its own

```
<div><p style="font-size: 13px;"><u><strong> Test 1</strong></u></p>

<p style="font-size: 13px;">blah blah blah</p>

<u style="line-height: 1.6em;"><strong>Test 2</strong></u>

<p>blah blah blah</p>
```

I only added the bold style.The font size 13 px is not added by me.Ckeditor automatically adds it. Is there a way to remove the auto formatting by Ckeditor?

Comment: If you show us the HTML it produces when it is stored then we can see what is up, otherwise we are just guessing

Comment: my default font is 18px. But why did the ckeditor added font-size:13px is puzzling me.

Comment: Hm... Does this happen on Webkit browser (Chrome/Safari/Opera)? If yes, then you're dealing with Webkit's bug. Read more here: http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9998

Comment: @Reinmar Thanks for info....but I searched for error, and came to know that error occurs when you copy and paste some text in ckeditor...I asked another question about it...as I thought I better explain the exact error...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657223/ckeditor-font-style-13-px...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my default font is 18px. But why did the ckeditor added font-size:13px
>   is puzzling me

If your default font is 18 px then the pasted text of 13px will appear small and if the default font size is 10 px then the pasted text will appear big.

So your best option is to change the default font size in ckeditor `contents.css` .
It will be located in your ckeditor folder.

```
 .cke_editable
    {
        font-size: 13px;
        line-height: 1.6em;
    }
```

Change the font-size to your default font size.

```
 .cke_editable
    {
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 1.6em;
    }
```

So all your font will be default set to 18 px.