# ckeditor font style 13 px

Tags: html, format, ckeditor, font-size

I had earlier asked question about it.
But after trying out all the possiblities where the error occurs, I have found that **in ckeditor if you copy some text and paste it, it is default pasted as 
    `<p style="font-size: 13px;">`**

example picture

[image: picture]

```
HTML CODE

<div><p>Original Text</p>

<p><strong><u>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</u></strong></p>

<p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>

<p>Copied Text</p>

<p style="font-size: 13px;"><strong><u>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</u></strong></p>

<p style="font-size: 13px;">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>
</div>
```

So if you know any solution to the above problem please answer me.
The problem starts when you copy a text and paste it.I am using ckeditor 4.Latest version.

Comment: There used to be a *paste as plain text* option in ckeditor I thought. Is it no longer there?

Comment: no but if you want to paste the bold and underlined text, then....? People dont use "paste as plain text" and apply format it to again..

Comment: and i think the text should be copied as it is...why add the extra font style 13 px? To show that it is copied text?

Comment: Does that happen to you with all the browsers or only Chrome and Safari?

Comment: I checked it in IE 10 n chrome 28...I think it occurs in all browser

Comment: Why is nobody answering...nobody gets this error? What people do to overcome this error? Please share your knowledge.Please.

Comment: You copy something and paste it, its font will be 13px. I am using ckeditor 4.

Comment: I don't answer again because I've tested with Firefox and IE10 and I can't reproduce your problem, so I don't know what you're doing.

Comment: @AlfonsoML I checked in ckeditor tickets and found a similar bug to mine. http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9754 ticket no 9754. But I could not understand whether they have solved it in newer versions or not. **Because I downloaded the standard 4.1.1 version and as you can see in image below, the error comes**. Can you tell me which version ckeditor u use?

Comment: Oh I came to know the error does not occur in firefox. In the bug also they complained about chrome only I think. So in firefox, the extra _font style 13px_ is **not generated** but in chrome it is generated when ever you paste some copied text.  _ And I am using chrome 28_                              @AlfonsoML _can you please download chrome and try it?_ You will see the error.

Comment: I know that Chrome is quite buggy with regards to editing contents, I don't need any special tests for that. And the CKEditor version doesn't really matter, because that problem has existed for quite sometime in webkit, but I can't reproduce your problem with IE10, so again, I don't know what are the specific reason why you have this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why isn't nobody answering?  I tried using the stable build 4.1.1 also. The problem is still there. What you people do to overcome this error?

See the error in ckeditor 4.1.1
[image: ckeditor]

The above one is preview mode. When I save the data in mysql and then retrive it, the style  is applied. And so the second Test will be smaller than usual.